# Match multiple values in a case of a switch

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement, indexof

I wonder if I can do a switch whose cases only fall when several values match.

I have an array with values 'X', 'O' or ' '. I want that when some values are 'X', fall through the case.

This is the idea:

```
switch(numbers.indexOf('X')) {
    case 0 && 1 && 2:
        //Do something
        break;
    case 2 && 3 && 4:
        //Do something
        break;
}
```

I know that I can do it with if - else easily, but I would like do it with a switch if it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: how can it be a `&&` , it's not possible ?

Comment: `0 && 1 && 2 === 0`, `2 && 3 && 4 === 4`, you probably want a fall-through.

Comment: Use `function` dude.. and reuse the code.

Comment: Mritunay is right.  You'll never get a single number to match two numbers.  :-)

Comment: use bit masks ... like below http://www.vipan.com/htdocs/bitwisehelp.html

Comment: Just skip break statement at the end of the case block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely what you'll want to do is stick the different functions you want to perform in their own section and then call them in each switch case. Sadly switch cases don't let you stack them like that, it would be lovely wouldn't it? Something like:

```
function a(){};
function b(){};
switch(x){
    case 0:
        a();
        break;
    case 1:
        a();
        break;
    case 2:
        b();
        break;
    case 3:
        b();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
switch(variable) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
  case 3:
    alert("Found necessary index");
    break;
  default:
    console.log(variable);
    break;
}
```